# Rendering images using GPU

Tags: c#, gpu, directx, directx-11

In one of the existing C# Winform program, an image is displayed. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the image display code but I know that there is a separate viewer, which uses DirectX to render the image.

**PROBLEM:** Now I have upgraded the camera to 4K, and the image display program takes approx. 90ms to render the image, which is too much for my application. Therefore, I wanted to test if I can reduce the image rendering time by using a GPU.

Only for testing, I ran the image display program with and without GPU. But it took exactly the same time in both situations. So, I think that DirectX is not automatically utilizing the benefit of GPU.

I am absolutely new to this graphics things and honestly, I am a bit puzzled now.

**Question:** Do I need to specify to the DirectX to use GPU? Will image rendering time improve by using a GPU? Any sample program where I can test the with/without GPU performance for image displaying task?

**System Configuration:**

- Windows-7 Embedded
- DirectX 11
- AMD GPU (some basic, I will update it details)

Comment: Winform use GDI to display images. To use DirectX you need to create a DirectX viewer and show your image in that viewer, otherwise you will always use the CPU.

Comment: I just mentioned that it's a Winform program but actually it has a separate viewer too, which uses DirectX to display images.

Comment: How did you test without GPU? It is very hard to say what's going on without seeing any code.

Comment: @skm Your viewer then must have an option called `HardwareAcceleration` or `AskForHardwareAcceleration` this option is usually a boolean or an enum property. What it does is when you set it to `True` if it see a display adapter (video card or integrated GPU) it will use it instead of the CPU. If it uses the integrated GPU on the CPU that is up to your Nvidia Profile (on nvidia card) to select the hardware to use for that executable.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I test with/without GPU by physically inserting and removing the graphics card. After inserting the graphics card, I installed its driver and cross-checked that it is enabled by running `dxdiag.exe` tool.

Comment: @Franck: As I said in my question, I do not have access to the source code. I just have DLLs. All I know is DirectX is used to render the images in a separate viewer. Therefore, I also asked in my question, if anyone can recommend me a sample C++/C# program where I check the performance with/without GPU.

Comment: @skm You won't be able to control their renderer unless it was OpenGL. You need to check the performance of what exactly ? you want to create your own separate project with rendering capability and see how long it take to render ? Are you talking of Ray Tracing ? Path Tracing, Cell Shaded, Bloom ? You have a lot of unanswered question. Most renderer on the market are still using CPU only. I personally use 5 different ones and 2 of those are Luxion and they are all CPU bound and not GPU. Cinema 4D is supposed to have a GPU version in a more recent version but that's rumors i heard.

Comment: @Franck: Your comment has made me think again if I am using the correct term "Image Rendering". Basically, I am grabbing images from a 4K camera which is connected to my PC via USB-3 Cable. Once I get an image, I want to display it on the monitor in real-time. Since the camera speed and data transfer bandwidth is quite high, the bottleneck is the image display program which is taking 100ms. I want to reduce the time to image display each image. The images captured by the camera are passed to a C# program which displays the images in a viewer using DirectX.

Comment: @skm This is different but in theory it "is" render as everything is rendered on screen. What you want is simply want to display and image in a form fast. You should update your question and yes that is possible and quite easy to achieve and test.

Comment: @Franck: Sorry for the silly question but what should I update in my question? I have already mentioned in the question that I want to improve the image display time of 4K images.